# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making an ajax call using jQuery as below.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "proc.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        alert(data.vote[0].line);    //Where error shows
    }
});
```

The php page returns `echo json_encode($string);` which is like

`"{ 'vote' : [{ 'line' : 'newline1', 'up' : '0', 'down' : '1'},
              { 'line' : 'newline2', 'up' : '4', 'down' : '1'}
             ]}"`

When I run it, an error comes up saying

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` on the line commented above in the ajax call

Can anyone help me point out where am I doing it wrong??

UPDATE:

the variable `$string` is generated as below

```
    $comma = ",";
    $success = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($success)){
            $voteUp = $row['voteup'];
            $voteDwn = $row['votedwn'];

            $vote .= $comma . "{ 'line' : '{$row['entryid']}', 'up' : '{$voteUp}', 'down' : '{$voteDwn}'";
            $comma = ",";
        }
    $string = "{ 'vote' : [" . $vote . "]}";
    echo json_encode($string);
```

Comment: @ptamzz can you make sure `alert(data);` prints the same string you have given in the question..

Comment: Please check the JSON string which `json_encode` creates with http://www.jsonlint.com/. `json_encode` should create a valid string but who knows...

Comment: @mithun: ye.. it gives the same data

Comment: @felix Kling: i checked at http://www.jsonlint.com/. it was showing invalid until i change ' to " (single quotes to double quotes). btw, do you know what's difference between the two??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jAHLx/ weird, that's working...

Comment: and now the json_encoded strings returns something like ` \"vote\" : [{ \"line\" : ..` with a \ in front of every double quotes... does the success function decode it automatically??

Comment: @ptamzz: Well, I assumed `json_encode` produces a valid string... weird. Keys and strings must be in double quotes in JSON. See http://json.org. What is the data you try to encode? Could you provide `var_export($string)`?

Comment: yup, Felix is right, how you are constructing `$string` in PHP?

Comment: It's better to json_encode() an array in PHP

Comment: please check the question.. updated part

Comment: What object type is `data` ? Do `alert(typeof data)` and see if you get object or string. If you can't work around it in the PHP use a client library for it like json.org/json2.js

Comment: Why are you creating a string in JSON format **and** passing it to `json_encode`? This is not how it works. Read the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of writing a "jsoned" string with PHP, use an array. `json_encode()` will do the magic

```
$return = array();

$success = mysql_query($query, $connection);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($success)) {
    $return['vote'][] = array(
        'line' => $row['entryid'],
        'up'   => $row['voteup'],
        'down' => $row['votedown'],
    );
}

echo json_encode($return);
```

Answer (score 3):

In the recent releases of jQuery, native browser JSON parsing methods are used instead of the traditional eval() approach. Strict JSON *does not support single quote strings*, which your example is using.
As previously mentioned, use json_encode($array) or fix your JSON manually

Comment: @LekisS: Because you are creating a JavaScript object, **not** JSON. , You can even omit the quotes around keys, if they are valid identifiers.